# How do I rebind event after widget save

Tags: widgets, jquery

I am writing a widget who's form elements have a click event attached to. I bind it using jQuery.

However, after clicking `save`, the bindings gets lost. That is, clicking those elements doesn't trigger the function anymore.

I tried using the `on()` jQuery method, as suggested [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4841/widget-save-resetting-jquery-hidden-fields), but that doesn't help:

```
    var buttonsHolder=jQuery('#widgets-right .icon_buttons');            
    // save the array of big icons, for later reference, and assign them the click event
    var  buttons=buttonsHolder.children('input');
    buttons.on("click",function(){
        openPanel(jQuery(this),jQuery(this).index());
    });
```

I could put my `js` code inside the widget form, as suggested [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4841/widget-save-resetting-jquery-hidden-fields). That does solve the problem, but I really prefer to keep my `js` code separated.

What do I need to do in order to keep the click event of those elements working even after the `save` button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the input box is getting rebuilt (or the entire form), I followed advice given me elsewhere, and instead of binding on() to an input box, I bind it higher up and use event delegation:

```
jQuery('#widgets-right').on('click','.icon_buttons input',function(){
     openPanel(jQuery(this),jQuery(this).index());
});
```

I still put some js variable declarations inside the widget form, but that's only for convenience, and it's only a few lines of code, so I don't mind it too much.

Answer (score 7):

Wordpress provides callbacks for widgets interactions. You're seems interested in two of them:

*widget-added, widget-updated*

Usage example:

```
jQuery(document).on('widget-updated', function(e, widget){
    // do your awesome stuff here
    // "widget" represents jQuery object of the affected widget's DOM element
});
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, and welcome to WPSE! Thanks so much for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm not working on that project anymore, so I can't test your answer. I do appreciate it, though, and hope it will help others who encounter the same problem :)

Comment: Hi, Lean, thank you :)

I believe, this comment will be useful for me too next time I work with widgets :)

Comment: Lea,
I apologize for misspelling your name, sorry!

Comment: Finally, a solution to my 2-year-long problem. Thank you!

Comment: See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/27969 for (slightly) more information...